# Unfollowing a post by clicking on the [following] button does not work on WebKit browsers (all iOS browsers and Mac Safari)

Tags: bug, status-review, follow-post, webkit

**Summary:**

With some browsers on macOS and iOS, unfollowing a question or answer dows not work anymore by clicking on the [following] button below the post.

The test results (below) strongly indicate that the problem occurs with all [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) based browsers.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Click on the [follow] button below a post to follow it. The button changes from [follow] to [following].
- Click on the [following] button to unfollow the post. A message “You're no longer following this question/answer” appears and the button changes from [following] to [follow].
- Refresh the page. The button changes from [follow] back to [following].
- Inbox notifications about answers/comments/edits still appear.
- The question or answer is still listed in the “Followed posts” tab on my profile page.

Removing the followed post on the profile page does work.

Observed on different sites (math.stackexchange.com, codereview.stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com).

**Tests:**

I have tested the behavior with different browsers on macOS 13 (Ventura) and on an iPhone with iOS 16. Test results which were reported in the comments but not verified by myself are marked.

| OS | Browser | Engine | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| macOS 13.5 | Safari 16.6 | WebKit | Bug |
| macOS 13.6 | Safari 17 | WebKit | OK |
| macOS 13.5 | Firefox 117 | Gecko | OK |
| macOS 13.5 | Google Chrome 116, 117 | Blink | OK |
| macOS 13.5 | Edge 116 | Blink | OK (1) |
| macOS 13.5 | Opera 102 | Blink | OK (1) |
| iOS 16.6 | Safari | WebKit | Bug |
| iOS 16.6 | Firefox 117 | WebKit | Bug |
| iOS 16.6 | Google Chrome 116, 117 | WebKit | Bug |

(1) Reported by [Elements in Space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/938841/elements-in-space) in a comment:

> Using macOS 13.5 I was able to reproduce with Safari 16.6 But not with Chrome 116, Edge 116, Firefox 117, or Opera 102.

**Analysis:**

This seems be be [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) specific problem since it occurs with all browsers using that engine (which at present includes *all* browsers on iOS, by Apple's policy), but not with other browsers on macOS.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Firefox 116

Comment: No repro on Chrome latest.

Comment: Check your browser console, do you see any client side errors? Do you have any userscripts that you can disable?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard: No userscripts, no messages in the console (as far as I can see).

Comment: Can you try with Chrome? If still not working, it would mean some odd problem with your account.

Comment: I was able to reproduce on Chrome iOS.

Comment: @Laurel: Thanks, good to know that I am not the only one! – Perhaps it is a WebKit related problem?

Comment: Using macOS 13.5 I was able to reproduce with Safari 16.6 But not with Chrome 116, Edge 116, Firefox 117, or Opera 102

Comment: @ElementsinSpace: *“But not with Chrome 116, ...”* – Chrome on Windows or  macOS?

Comment: I tried all 5 browsers on the same computer macOS 13.5

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard: The bug does not occur with Chrome or Firefox on macOS, only with Safari.

Comment: Chrome uses the Blink engine and Firefox uses Gecko. Neither of those use WebKit.

Comment: @forestdistrustsStackExchange: What you say is correct for Chrome and Firefox on macOS and Windows. On iOS devices, apps can only be installed from Apple's App Store, and those are *required* to use WebKit ([Source:](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) *“2.5.6 Apps that browse the web must use the appropriate WebKit framework and WebKit JavaScript.”*) – That fits also with the observation that the bug occurs with Chrome/Firefox on iOS, but not with Chrome/Firefox on macOS.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting! I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: Similar problem reported at MSO: [Unfollowing link on posts not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426611/unfollowing-link-on-posts-not-working)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Yes, that one is about FireFox on Debian. Other one is here: [Find that it fails to unfollow a question sometimes recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393288/196432) (Chrome on macOS, which I can not reproduce so far).

Comment: @MartinR I intermediately experience the problem with Firefox on macOS. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not ...

Comment: Turn out Safari 16 is not supported, so any feature might or might not work for those using it.